# Apply a cumulative and operator on a Matlab array

Tags: matlab, logic, and-operator

How do I apply logical operators to a Matlab array in a "sum" fashion?

For example : and([1 0 0]) = 0, and([1 1 1]) = 1.

Comment: also prod([1 0 0]) for 'and' and (sum([1 0 0]) > 0) for 'or' but I think any() and all() are better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:

```
a = [1,0,0]
```

then you can say:

```
any(a) %% which is equivalent to 'or'

all(a) %% which is equivalent to 'and'
```